# Conceptualizing the (set theoretic) universe as a relation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

The universe is the class $\mathcal{U} = \{x: x = x\} = \{x: x \text{ is a set}\}$.

Is there a way to define the universe in terms of a relation $R = \{(x,y): \psi(x,y)\}$, where $\psi(x,y)$ is some set theoretic formula in which $x$ and $y$ are the only free variables?

My question stems from having been given the following exercise:

> What is $\mathcal{U}^{-1}$? Hint: recall that $R^{-1} = \{(x,y): (y,x)
>  \in R\}$.

I am having difficulty making sense of the question itself as I am having a hard time conceptualizing the universe as a relation.

Edit: The notion of ordered pairs I am given is $(x,y) = \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$.

Comment: I can't make sense of the question either; if $\mathcal{U}$ *is* a relation then all of its elements are ordered pairs, but $\varnothing$ is not an ordered pair (unless your encoding of ordered pairs allows for this—the 'standard' one doesn't).

Comment: @CliveNewstead Thanks. I added the definition of ordered pairs we are using (from Halmos), which I believe is the standard definition.

Comment: That is indeed the 'standard' definition of ordered pair I was referring to. This means that, unless either $\mathcal{U}$ or 'relation' or 'ordered pair' is redefined somehow, $\mathcal{U}$ certainly *can't* be considered to be a relation. [In other words, the question you've been asked doesn't make any sense, unless there's something else you're missing.]

Comment: I don't know much about set theory, but for what it's worth, I can't see anything troublesome in the definition of $\mathscr{U}^{-1}$. The definition of $R^{-1}$ in general doesn't require $R$ to be a relation, does it? It's just that it only tends to be *useful* when $R$ is a relation. If I'm not mistaken about that, then the question "What is $\mathscr{U}$?" does seem to have a fairly simple answer - even if not a very interesting one!

Comment: @CalumGilhooley I think the definition does require $R$ to be a relation. What would it mean to “take the inverse” of something that isn’t a relation?

Comment: [Excuse the typo, by the way. I can't edit my comment now.] I've just looked it up in Suppes, *Axiomatic Set Theory* (1972 Dover reprint). He writes [p.61]: "The definition is so framed that members of sets which are not ordered pairs do not belong to the converse of the set, and thus the converse of every set is a relation."

Comment: $R^{-1}$ is well-defined for any class $R$. If $R$ is not a relation, i.e., if some of its members are not ordered pairs, then those members have no effect on $R^{-1}$.

Comment: @TuringTester69: That's an odd question.  The text quite literally gives you a definition of what it means to "take the inverse", namely $R^{-1}=\{(x,y):(y,x)\in R\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the following definitions (as, for example, in Kelley's set theory)
$$\{x\}=\{z:z\,\text{set}\implies z=x\}$$
$\{x,y\}=\{x\}\cup\{y\}$ and $(x,y)=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\} $.
Then $(x,y) $ is a set if and only if both $x $ and $y $ are sets.
Consequently, we have
\begin{align}
\mathcal U^{-1}
&=\{(y,x):(x,y)\in\mathcal U\}\\
&=\{(y,x):x,y\in\mathcal U\}\\
&=\mathcal U\times\mathcal U
\end{align}

Comment: Prove your claim.  By the first two lines it is U.

Comment: In other words, $\mathcal U^{-1}$ is the class of all ordered pairs.

Answer (score 0):

No, $\mathcal{U}$ is not a relation and there is not any useful way to conceptualize it as one.  But the problem you are trying to solve in no way requires $\mathcal{U}$ to be a relation.  Just use the definition: $$\mathcal{U}^{-1}=\{(x,y):(y,x)\in\mathcal{U}\}.$$  In other words, $\mathcal{U}^{-1}$ is the class of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ such that $(y,x)\in\mathcal{U}$.  For which $x$ and $y$ is $(y,x)\in\mathcal{U}$?  If you can answer that, then you know what the elements of $\mathcal{U}^{-1}$ are.